# Python: efficiently checking a file line by line

Tags: python, performance, file, if-statement, for-loop

I have very large text files (around 1.5 million or more lines) to parse for some information. Each line I do checks for certain keywords (I call them "flags").

However, there are dozens of checks I run for each line, so my program takes a considerable amount of time to finish. Is there a faster way to how I am currently checking? Below is just an example of what I am doing:

```
nameFound = false
ageFound = false

for line in file:
    if not nameFound and line.find('name:') != -1:
        do something
    elif not ageFound and line.find('age:') != -1:
        do something
    elif line.find('test pass') != -1:
        do something
    elif line.find('test fail') != -1:
        do something
    and so on ...
```

Some of the "flags" only appear once (although I do not know where in the file or in what order), so I use a "found" variable to short-circuit my checks for those "flags". Other information appears thousands of times, so I can not use a "found" variable in my conditions. **One thing I know is that each line, if it contains a "flag", will only have one flag at maximum.** With that information in mind, is there a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: I would first run a Python profiler on your code to find where the performance bottlenecks are. [https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). Amend your question with the results and we can work from there.

Comment: I think your use of `elif` statements is the most efficient way of performing short-circuit testing for flags.

Comment: You're doing a lot of extra work, because for each each flag you fail, you parse the _entire_ line again.

Comment: `in` is significantly faster than `str.find`.

Comment: I change the code to **in** instead, but I did not see much notable improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a suggestion: you can use a list of "flags", and iterate through them.

```
flags = [('name:', nameMethod), ('age:', ageMethod), ('test pass', tpMethod), ('test fail', tfMethod), ... ] #methods are functions without ()

for line in lines:
  for flag, func in flags:
    if line.find(flag) != -1:
      func(args) #your args
      break #same functionality as elif
```

By the way, using the `in` operator is better than `str.find` or `str.index`. So `if flag in line: #do something`.

This is just for readability. You should definitely do profiling to identify bottlenecks, and then see what should/shouldn't be fixed. I *do* know for sure that using `in` instead of `str.find` is much more efficient (about 3 times by my testing estimations).

Comment: Thanks, using the **in** operator helped a lot. Also is there a way to implement your flags list with the short circuiting method? Or should i not bother with it at all?

Comment: @mistasong a list only improves readability. I do not think that there would be considerable time difference between for loops and if statements, but you can do timings using the `time` module.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, there isn't much you could do to speed things up.  You're going line by line, only reading the file once.  You've already done plenty to "squeeze" more speed out of your loop with short circuiting.  The amount of time your code takes to run is proportional to the size of the file.

It may be better for you to first filter the file's lines with a faster tool.  For instance, the `grep` Unix command is generally implemented in C, and is very fast (much faster than implementing the loop in Python).  So, you could use a command like this (on Linux or Unix) to filter the lines, and then run your program on the filtered file:

```
grep "flag1\|flag2\|flag3" big.txt > filtered.txt
```

Another option might be using [Cython](http://cython.org/) to attempt to speed up your code by compiling it to C.  But realistically, that won't gain you *that* much.

Comment: Useless use of `cat` detected!

Comment: Yeah, I always forget the order of parameters for grep, so I just cat or pipe the text in...  I looked it up and in the man page and fixed it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider it: every single `if` searches the *entire* line for a (possibly non-existent) flag.

Suppose your line was 'Daddy has reached the airport', and your list of flags was ['M', 'Mommy'] then it is obvious that if M could not be found, Mommy will not be found either.

If you are willing to take the effort to implement them, the [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) or [Rabin-Karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) algorithms will offer significant speed-ups.

Answer (score 0):

A regex search might be faster:

```
import re
flags = "name|age|etc"

for line in file:
    m = re.match(flags, line)
    if m.group():
        do_something(m)
```

Alternatively, you could put all your tests in a while loop so that it will exit as soon as it finds a flag:

```
flags = ['name', 'age', 'foo']

for line in file:
    i = 0
    while i < len(flags):
        if (line.find(flags[i])):
            do_something(flags[i])
            i = len(flag[i]) 
        i += 1
```

If you need to do something different for each flag, you can put that logic in a method.